# Sending http requests from docker container using same network as sending requests from host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, ip-address, docker-network

My application is `dockerized`. Its `python/django` application. We are using a local sms sending api that is restricted on IP based. So I have given them my `EC2` ip address. And I am running my docker container in this `EC2` machine. But my python app is not able to send requests to that machine. Because this docker container has different IP.

How do I solve this problem ?

**Dockerfile**

```
# ToDo use alpine image
FROM python:3.6
# Build Arguments with defaults
ARG envior
ARG build_date
ARG build_version
ARG maintainer_name='Name'
ARG maintainaer_email='email@email.com'
# Adding Labels
LABEL com.example.service="Service Name" \
      com.example.maintainer.name="$maintainer_name" \
      com.example.maintainer.email="$maintainaer_email" \
      com.example.build.enviornment="$envior" \
      com.example.build.version="$build_version" \
      com.example.build.release-date="$build_date"
# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /home/example/app
# Install Libre Office for pdf conversion
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -y -q libreoffice \
    && apt-get remove -q -y libreoffice-gnome
# Cleanup after apt-get commands
RUN apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*cache.bin
# Activate WORKING DIR
WORKDIR /home/example/app
# Copying requirements
COPY requirements/${envior}.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
# Install the app dependencies
# ToDo Refactor requirements
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
# Envs
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE app.settings.${envior}
ENV ENVIORNMENT ${envior}
# ADD the source code and entry point into the container
ADD . /home/example/app
ADD entrypoint.sh /home/example/app/entrypoint.sh
# Making entry point executable
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
# Exposing port
EXPOSE 8000
# Entry point and CMD
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/example/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: onjin/alpine-postgres:9.5
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      LC_ALL: C.UTF-8
      POSTGRES_USER: django
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: django
      POSTGRES_DB: web
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        environ: local
    command: gunicorn app.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://django:django@postgres/web'
      DJANGO_MANAGEPY_MIGRATE: 'on'
      DJANGO_MANAGEPY_COLLECTSTATIC: 'on'
      DJANGO_LOADDATA: 'off'
      DOMAIN: '0.0.0.0'

volumes:
   postgres_data:
```

Comment: Please provide relevant parts of configuration files. Did you publish any port from the container on EC2?

Comment: @trust512 added dockerfile

Comment: Meaning you have no compose/terraform/kube files?

Comment: @trust512 Sorry mate. I have added compose now.

Comment: From this perspective looks totally fine, `Ashok`'s answer is no longer valid. Looks like there is something "higher". Could you provide details on relevant AWS elastic IP / ELB setup? Additionally, can you reach the application manually from your host (via curl for example)? On top of the above - is the application actually running fine (looking at compose logs and localhost curl'ing)?

Comment: @trust512 application is running fine and I am having no issues. when we access sms_sending_api from ec2, it is working fine but from docker container, it is not accessable. because docker has different ip than its host and we have registered ec2 ip on sms_sending_api. I just want to do something so that outgoing requests from docker container should be treated as they were going  from ec2.

Comment: Ah, and now you cleared the situation. I think I have a solution for you but I have to test it first.

Comment: @trust512  let me try that

Comment: I have answered with that solution below - in case you didn't receive any notification.

Comment: @trust512 Please edit this question so that others might find it easily. I know I have not been able to explain it properly. Also please upvote the question too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try putting the container in the same network as your EC2 instance. It means using networks with `host` driver.

suggested **docker-compose** file

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    [...]
    networks:
      - host
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  web:
    [...]
    networks:
      - host

volumes:
   postgres_data:

networks:
  host:
```

In case it wouldn't work, you might define your own network by:

```
networks:
  appnet:
    driver: host
```

and connect to that network form services:

```
postgres:
    [..]  
    networks:
      - appnet
```

Further reading about networks [official ref](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode). 
An interesting read too from [official networking tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/#procedure).

Answer (score 0):

Publish port from docker container to base machine, then configure ec2IP:port   in sms application.